# The best way to deprecate all class methods in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deprecated, class-method, deprecation-warning

I have a class (and it is not an `ActiveRecord` model) having multiple class methods. All the class methods must be deprecated. What's the best way to do this?

```
class MyClass
  class << self
    def method_to_deprecate_1
      ...
    end
    ...
    def method_to_deprecate_100
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Just insert a `Kernel.warn` (or something similar) into every affected method body.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev That's what I'm trying to avoid. Too many methods. Looking for a single-liner.

Comment: Even with 100 methods, this is 30 minutes of work tops. And you mark exactly the methods you want to deprecate. No more, no less. In my book, this is better than a piece of MP that affects unknown/variable number of methods.

Comment: @MaksymPolshcha just updated my original answer to address your needs, I hope that will help you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ruby has a special module [Gem::Deprecate](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.6.0/Gem/Deprecate.html) for that, here's an example from the official documentation:

```rb
class Legacy
  def self.klass_method
    # ...
  end

  def instance_method
    # ...
  end

  extend Gem::Deprecate
  deprecate :instance_method, "X.z", 2011, 4

  class << self
    extend Gem::Deprecate
    deprecate :klass_method, :none, 2011, 4
  end
end
```

It will result to:

```rb
2.5.0 :020 > Legacy.new.instance_method
NOTE: Legacy#instance_method is deprecated; use X.z instead. It will be removed on or after 2011-04-01.
Legacy#instance_method called from (irb):20.
 => nil 
2.5.0 :021 > Legacy.klass_method
NOTE: Legacy.klass_method is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-04-01.
Legacy.klass_method called from (irb):21.
 => nil
```

Edit:
To answer your question directly, here is the most elegant way I could imagine to deprecate ALL of the class methods:

```rb
class Kek
   class << self
     def old_method_1
       # ...
     end

     def old_method_2
       # ...
     end

     extend Gem::Deprecate

     # instance methods here are our actual class methods + all of the Object's methods from Ruby
     instance_methods(false).each { |method_to_deprecate| deprecate(method_to_deprecate, :none, 2011, 4) }
   end
end
```

Comment: What about `instance_methods(false).each { |method_to_deprecate|...}`, but shouldn't that be done after the class has been created (`Kek.methods(false).each { 'method_to_deprecate|...}`? It also may be cleaner to invoke `Kek.extend Gem::Deprecate` after the class is created.

Comment: thank you, @CarySwoveland! 
I've edited my answer with `instance_methods(false)`. Didn't knew it is possible, there's always an easier solution in Ruby :)

About deprecating after the class is created...  `deprecate` is a private method and is not available after the class creation. Even if it wasn't, this means you would need to deprecate the methods every time you use `Kek` class in a new file as far as I can understand.

Comment: Shouldn't `extend Gem::Deprecate` be `include Gem::Deprecate`, since it is within `class << self ... end`? Better, imo, is `extend Gem::Deprecate` outside the singleton class construct. I believe `instance_methods(false).each { ...}` should also be outside, though I am still of the opinion given in my first comment.

Comment: Re your comment: given that the class methods of `Kek` are being deprecated, it might be advisable to put `Kek` in a separate module to be required, in which case the module could also contain `Kek.extend Gem::Deprecate; Kek.methods(false).each { |method_to_deprecate| Kek.send(method_to_deprecate, ...) }`.